# Make the KWIN cube act like the Compiz Cube

Tags: kde, kwin

So, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE installed. I like the 3D cube in KWin and I also like KWin's effects, but I prefer the way Compiz handles it's cube and key bindings. I was wondering if there was a way to make KWin's cube act exactly like Compiz's cube, with the only difference being I don't want to move to the next or previous desktop when dragging and dropping a window to the edge of the screen. So, I should be able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> to switch between desktops and such.

Answer (score 0):

The titles I mention are relevant to `systemsettings5`, but they're also present in other versions — just, perhaps, might have a bit different name.

Disable desktop switch when dragging window to an edge:

- `systemsettings5 → Desktop Behaviour → Screen Edges`, set the drop down list `Switch desktop on edge` to `Disabled`.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> to switch desktops:

- `systemsettings5 → Desktop Behaviour → Virtual Desktops`, the tab `Switching`, shortcuts `Switch to Next Desktop` and `Switch to Previous Desktop`.

Don't forget that System Settings has a textbox to search in the upper-right corner, e.g. you can enter there `edge`, and the settings that mention the word would be highlighted.